# .NET Select USB drive as default FolderBrowserDialog path

Tags: .net, vb.net, path, usb, folderbrowserdialog

Hi to all programming gurus,

Currently the path(folder) is selected by clicking the button.

```
Private Sub SelectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectButton.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Path.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

End Sub
```

What are the ways to **make USB drive path** as **default FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath**?

Thanks!

Comment: `FolderBrowserDialog1.InitialDirectory = "F://" ` The USB path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
    Dim folder = New FolderBrowserDialog()
    Dim drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim usbDrive = drives.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.DriveType = System.IO.DriveType.Removable)
    folder.SelectedPath = usbDrive.RootDirectory.FullName
    If folder.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show(folder.SelectedPath)
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Mind to explain a bit on Function(m) there? New to programming here. Thanks!

Comment: Function(m) is a lambda expression, representing a function. You can have a further learning about lambda expression through here: [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions)